# Sub Gruntfile.js Herdando node_modules da raiz

Tags: grunt, npm

Estou em um projeto (em laravel 4.2) onde fizeram um mega Gruntfile.js, ai resolvi organizar e criar um Gruntfile.js para cada conjunto de "assets" de projetos.

O Problema: Eu não quero ter que dar um 'npm install' pra cada subprojeto (porque pra cada subprojeto eu tenho um Gruntfile.js e um package.json), então tentei forçar a leitura do node_modules que ja existe na raiz, com:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) { "use strict";

//força path do node_modules (pra nao ter que baiar novamente)
grunt.file.setBase('../../../');

//força a leitura das dependencias do package.json principal
require("matchdep").filterDev("grunt-*").forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON("package.json"), //meu atual
    ...
});
}
```

Isto funcionou +ou- poque quando forço o dir no 'node_modules' ele também lê o Gruntfile.js da raiz e ai acaba executando algumas tarefas indesejadas Estrutura do Projeto

Alguém tem uma luz?

Estrutura do Projeto: 
/app 
/xpto 
/public 
    /assets 
         /proj1 
                 /js 
                 /css 
                 /img 
                 **-Gruntfile.js** 
                 **-package.json** 
         /proj2 
                 /js 
                 /css 
                 /img 
                 **-Gruntfile.js** 
                 **-package.json** 
**Gruntfile.js** (padrao) 
**package.json** (padrao)

Comment: Imagino que cada um desses projetos evolua a um ritmo diferente e mais cedo ou mais tarde precises de versões atualizadas de alguns módulos ao mesmo tempo que outros devem ter versões fixas para não partir código que funciona. Apesar de parecer trabalho a mais acho que cada projeto deve ter o seu package.json e o se npm install. Senão não são projetos diferentes mas sim o mesmo projeto.

Comment: @Sergio na vdd são sub themes dentro de um projeto só.
Achei que teria uma maneira mais inteligente de se aproveitar os npm_modules do grunt, ja que a maioria das tarefas são macantes: compilar less, minificar, gerar sprites

Answer (score 0):

Meu código estva funcionando, ele só lia o Gruntfile.js pai durante o comando "watch"

Coloquei nessa task um um options: {cwd:""} e funcionou 100% agora